# build success but run fail for Stack class

Tags: c++

So, I am trying to run the class below with

```
int x = 5;
mystack<int> st;
st.push(x);
```

However, I keep getting build failure, I can't seem to figure out why.

```
#ifndef MYSTACK_H
#define MYSTACK_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class mystack {
private:
    vector<T> data;
    int size = 0;
public:
    void push(T const &);
};

template<typename T>
void mystack<T>::push(T const & elem) {

    data[size] = elem;
    size++;
}
```

RUN FAILED ( exit value -1, 073, 741, 819, total time: 1s)

---

Also completely separate question, how do I throw an underflow? I tried

```
throw underflow_error();
```

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question body. Your question body is missing the relevant error messages (verbatim please).

Comment: Title says "build success" and question indicates "build failure". Which is it and what exactly does the error state?

Comment: You want to add `data.resize(size + 1);`  as the first line of `push`. Operator `[]` does no bounds checking

Comment: .. Or perhaps `push_back` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back would be better

Comment: Thanks, how would you write a resize function? I am trying to make a Stack class without using vector STL

Comment: Your code is using `vector`. Perhaps write a new question

Comment: "*I am trying to make a Stack class without using vector STL*" -- But you didn't even get the `vector` part correct in your post, and that was very easy.  Creating your own `vector` class is much more involved, even though you may think it is just a "function".

Comment: So, "RUN FAILED" is compiler error, I suppose. What is the actual error message? Please *edit* the question to show full compiler output (if you are using an IDE, click around the windows, panes and menus until you find it as text, which you can copy-paste).

Answer (score 3):

Initially your `vector<T> data` is empty. Its `size()` is 0. You cannot access to any of its elements. That might be the reason of getting an error.

Try using this code:

```
template<typename T>
void mystack<T>::push(T const & elem) {
    data.push_back(elem);
}
```

It actually will increase you `data.size()` by 1 every time you `push` an element.

> Don't want to use any vector STL

Wonder you are having `vector<T>` in code, looks like STL. You can use plain dynamic arrays as an alternative or even static ones.

```
template<typename T>
class mystack {
private:
    T* data;
    int size = 0;
    int maxSize;
public:
    mystack(int maxSize) :maxSize(maxSize) { data = new data[maxSize]; }
    ~mystack() { delete[] data; }
    void push(T const &);
};

template<typename T>
void mystack<T>::push(T const & elem) {
    // here you may check if you already reached the maxSize;
    data[size++] = elem;
}
```

Note that in order to fully simulate STL vector behaviour you should consider reallocating the array each time you have `size = allocateSize`. STL vector makes this every time the number of elements hits the power of 2, it doubles its size.

Comment: Don't want to use any vector STL

Comment: @BrianJones But by using `std::vector`, you're already using STL. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My own Stack class from scratch, so push_back would be kind of cheating lol.

Comment: @BrianJones I suggest you get your original post working first with `vector`, so as to ensure that at least, the class actually works correctly.  Then if it works with `vector`, *then* concern yourself with creating your own class without vector.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to use `std::stack` instead of implement your own stack using `std::vector`. If you don't want use STL at all, your should control memory allocation and deletion by yourself. In your example, in the line `data[size] = elem;`, you assign value to not allocated memory, it is your problem. You can fix it that way, if you don't want to use `push_back()` method:

```
template<typename T>
void mystack<T>::push(T const & elem) {
    size += 1;
    data.resize(size);
    data[size] = elem;
}
```

About `std::underflow_error`. It designed for arithmetic underflow errors. Anyway, this class has constructor where your should put string, so you need change `throw underflow_error();` to `throw underflow_error("Error message");`.